# Jekyll: ERROR files not found

Tags: jekyll

I just setup a local jekyll instance for github pages.  After following all the instructions on GitHub and getting all the files into the local repository, I ran jekyll (sudo bundle exec jekyll serve).

I get the following errors:

```
^CSeans-MacBook-Air:docs-gh-pages seanmcintyre$ sudo bundle exec jekyll serve
Password:
Configuration file: none
Configuration file: none
            Source: /Users/SnapRouteDocs/docs-gh-pages
       Destination: /Users/SnapRouteDocs/docs-gh-pages/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.82 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/SnapRouteDocs/docs-gh-pages'
Configuration file: none
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
[2017-04-13 13:35:12] ERROR `/_static/js/modernizr.min.js' not found.
[2017-04-13 13:35:12] ERROR `/_static/js/theme.js' not found.
[2017-04-13 13:35:12] ERROR `/_static/doctools.js' not found.
[2017-04-13 13:35:12] ERROR `/_static/jquery.js' not found.
[2017-04-13 13:35:12] ERROR `/_static/underscore.js' not found.
[2017-04-13 13:35:17] ERROR `/_static/css/theme.css' not found.
[2017-04-13 13:35:17] ERROR `/_static/jquery.js' not found.
[2017-04-13 13:35:17] ERROR `/_static/underscore.js' not found.
[2017-04-13 13:35:17] ERROR `/_static/doctools.js' not found.
[2017-04-13 13:35:17] ERROR `/_static/js/theme.js' not found.
```

I've checked and all the files are actually there.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 4):

Prob because Jekyll doesn't know about them, so they're not compiling into the build folder, `_site`. Try adding this in the `_config.yml` file:

```
include:
  - _static
```

If that doesn't work, just remove the underscore and Jekyll will automatically include in the build. That's prob best way anyway.

Comment: This method also works with directories starting with `.` (hidden)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @keruilin's answer, Jekyll errors such as

```
ERROR `/resources/biokdd-review-nlp.htm' not found.
```

are sometimes simply due to a malformed web URL, in one of your Jekyll-built site pages that are open in your browser.  Check the open webpages, and reload.

In my case (for instance) if I manually / erroneously open the malformed URL

```
127.0.0.1:4000/resources/biokdd-review-nlp. html
```

(note the space before `.html` I get that Jekyll error, until I correct the URL and reload the page.